# How to find the latest binlog of MariaDB by shell script?

Tags: linux, mysql, shell-scripting

I want to find the latest mysql binary log in `/var/log/mysql/`, but I found the name of binlog is `mariadb-bin.0000*`, and we also have `mysql-bin.index`, so it's really hard for me to use shell script to distinguish them. My idea is finding binlogs by their file type, which is "Mysql replication log", then sort them by modification time, but I don't know how to do it.

Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ls -1t /var/log/mysql/mariadb-bin.*` will return you the list of files sorted, most recent first. That might be mariadb-bin.index.

If you want the last binlog only, you can combine it with grep -v (wich will exclude what you grep) and head.
`ls -1t /var/log/mysql/mariadb-bin.* | grep -v "mariadb-bin.index" | head -n 1`

Comment: I tried this one, but it shows mariadb-bin.index, not the binlog I want. In my case, the modification time of binlog and mariadb-bin.index is the same, so I want to distinguish them by their file types.

Comment: ah you wrote it's mysql-bin.index in your initial post. Then you should use ` ls -1t /var/log/mysql/mariadb-bin.* | grep -v "mariadb-bin.index" | head -n 1`

Comment: But what if there are many binlogs, which the number exceeds the limit?

Comment: I edited my comment just before yours